# Symfony: how to mock services (FormBuilder and Router)

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I have an handler i wrote that has the following signature:

```
public function __construct(
    Store $store,
    array $orders,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    Router $router)
{
```

How can i mock FormFactory and Router?

I've tryied the following:

```
$formFactory = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory')
$router = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router')
```

But i receive the following error:

> AppBundle\Tests\Handler\SetUpHandlerTest::testConstructor Argument 1
>   passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
>   called in
>   /DevRoot/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php
>   on line 254 and defined

It seems there is a problem with the interface ContainerInterface.

How can i mock this service?

Comment: Yes, now the test works! Thank you!
(If you delete this comment and put your answer as a real answer i will vote it as the best one for this question).

Comment: deleted and reposted, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly disable the constructor.

> $formFactory->disableOriginalConstructor();

Consider that your mock extends your initial object, therefore unless you disable the constructor it will expect the dependencies still.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces like FormFactoryInterface and UrlGeneratorInterface are more preferable to be mocked. It means that you know only about method's signature, but neither about realisation.